# macOS Calendar default not available

Tags: macos, calendar, exchange

I am using the Apple Calendar app on Big Sur (11.4). I connected it to an Exchange account and can see the calendar events. However, I cannot set the default calendar in preferences:

[image: preferences]

There are no calendars listed:

[image: default calendar]

When I add a new event from a .ics file, it gets added to a new calendar:

[image]

Then I end up with my original calendar as well as a new calendar just for the new event:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 calendar? If not, what issue are you trying to solve? I have a Mac with 1 exchange calendar and I see the same. Possibly exchange doesn't communicate as well with ical as icloud/google.

Comment: @JBallin The problem is that new events get added to a new calendar, not to the one Exchange calendar.

Comment: Can you give more details about the “new calendar”? Which service is it from

Comment: Also - you understand that you can just “select” the calendar you want to create new events in, right? This is done in the left drawer when viewing the calendar.

Comment: It creates a new calendar just for the new event. Then I can edit the event and move it to the original calendar. Then I delete the newly created calendar.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the side drawer with the new calendar?

Comment: I updated the question with more screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this and was frustrated with it (enough to open an account here just to reply). I only have one CalDAV account as I use IMAP for mail. My work around was to turn iCloud calendar on then minimise it in the left side as well as untick it. Events now get added to my personal account and I can set it as my default while the iCloud calendar sits empty in the background.

I have opened a case with Apple and they have confirmed the bug and submitted it to engineering for review/fixing.

Comment: Activating iCloud calendar allowed me to select the default calendar in preferences (both iCloud and the Exchange account were listed as options). I am extremely flattered that you opened an account here just to answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: this answer assumes that turning on iCloud calendar is not an option.

Importing `.ics` files into an Exchange calendar using Mac's Calendar.app does not appear to be supported (and neither does the "Default Calendar" setting).

You should import the files into Outlook directly.

Comment: Did this change in Big Sur? It was supported before.

Comment: Not sure if it was supported in Big Sur, I’ve always used Outlook for my exchange calendar.